# Динамические ссылки для mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php

Всем привет!

Хочу, чтобы по запросу

```
site.com/blog/category/article-1/
```

показывалось

```
site.com/articles/article-1/
```

Мой код mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ articles/$2/ [L]
```

работает, и при запросе *site.com/blog/category/article-1/* я действительно вижу *site.com/articles/article-1/*, **НО** при этом меняется содержимое адресной строки браузера (станет *site.com/articles/article-1/*)!

Однако если я перепишу mod_rewrite так (укажу статический url)

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ articles/article-1/ [L]
```

то всё будет хорошо и содержимое адресной строки браузера не изменится, то есть останется *site.com/blog/category/article-1/*.

**UPDATE**

Кэш чищу каждый раз.
Возможно проблема с другими правилами в .htaccess, привожу всё, что есть
    #Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ articles/$2/ [L]

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Rewrite domain.com -> www.domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=permanent,L] .

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае у вас, вероятно, в конце строки указано [R,L]

Comment: Нет, скопировал как есть. Только [L] там

Comment: Обновил вопрос другими правилами, может, проблема где-то там?